# Find operation and highlight the word using jquery

Tags: jquery

When I am doing the find operation on above htmltext for "the", it should highlight the "the" word with background color using span tag like

```
<span class="highlight">the</span>
```

result :

```
<p style="font-size:12pt; line-height:115%; margin:0pt"><span style="font-family:Calibri; font-size:12pt">[Pick <span class="highlight">the</span> date] a n d s height</span></p>
```

Comment: var htmltext = '<p style="font-size:12pt; line-height:115%; margin:0pt"><span style="font-family:Calibri; font-size:12pt">[Pick the date] a n d s height</span></p>'

Comment: but result coming as:

Comment: '<p style="font-size:12pt; line-height:115%; margin:0pt"><span style="font-family:Calibri; font-size:12pt">[Pick <span class="highlight">the</span> date] a n d s height</span></p>'

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<p style="font-size:12pt; line-height:115%; margin:0pt">
<span style="font-family:Calibri; font-size:12pt" id="targetSpan">[Pick the date] a n d s height</span>
</p>
```

jquery

```
var spanText = $('#targetSpan').html().replace("the","<span class='highlight'>the</span>");
$('#targetSpan').html(spanText);
```